# windows 2008 teredo server

Tags: windows-server-2008

How to set up teredo server on windows server 2008 ?
netsh interface teredo set state help
displays
type=disabled|client|enterpraiseclient|default

there is no server type

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Windows offers any Teredo Server functionality out-of-the-box. You might take a look at the following (not Windows-base), if you need to set one up - http://linux.die.net/man/8/miredo-server.